# Why can I click on a hidden JLabel?

Tags: java, click, jlabel

I'm making a GUI with Java.
I'm using JLabel and with this code i give them some "onclick" events :

```
myJLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){  
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
       System.out.println("Yeah !!!!");
    }
});
```

And it's working, the "Yeah !!!!" is print.
The problem is if i have an other JLabel above "myJLabel", i still can click on "myJLabel".
Here are some images to explain :
"myJLabel" is the red JLabel. When i click on it, the pink JLabel is moving. So everything is ok :D)
[image]
But if the pink JLabel is above "myJLabel", i still can click on it :'(.
[image]
My question is : How can I prevent it ?

---

EDIT : Here is my full code :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.accessibility.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test extends JPanel{
    private String[] layerStrings = { "Yellow (0)", "Magenta (1)", "Cyan (2)",   "Red (3)", "Green (4)" };
    private Color[] layerColors = { Color.yellow, Color.magenta, Color.cyan, Color.red, Color.green };

    private JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    private JLabel dukeLabel;

    public Test(){
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        //Create and set up the layered pane.
        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 310));
        layeredPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));


        JLabel label1 = createColoredLabel(layerStrings[1], layerColors[1], new Point(10, 10));
        JLabel label2 = createColoredLabel(layerStrings[2], layerColors[2], new Point(30, 30));

        label1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){  
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
               System.out.println("Yeah !!!!");
            }
       });

        layeredPane.add(label1, new Integer(1));
        layeredPane.add(label2, new Integer(2));

        add(layeredPane);
    }

    //Create and set up a colored label.
    private JLabel createColoredLabel(String text, Color color, Point origin) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
        label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBackground(color);
        label.setForeground(Color.black);
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        label.setBounds(origin.x, origin.y, 140, 140);
        return label;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("LayeredPaneDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        JComponent newContentPane = new Test();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: Of course, look at the edit :D

Comment: The main reason I "think" it's happening, is when a mouse event occurs, Swing is looking for the first component with a registered listener.  Case in point, if I add a `MouseListener` to `label2`, it works you are expecting, you can't click through it.  Depending on what you are trying to do, you could add a `MouseListener` to the `JLayeredPane` and then determine if the any one of the components can be clicked, based on their z-order or simply add `MouseListener`s to all you labels :P

Comment: That's true ! You can put it as a solution, i will validate it. But it's a little bit ugly xD

Answer (score 0):

In the event function add this command. Basically says if it is not showing, doing nothing.

```
if(!this.isShowing())return;
```

Comment: Thanks, but isShowing is a function i'll have to create right ?

Comment: no it should be a built in function.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.AccessibleJLayeredPane.html

myJLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){  
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
       if(!this.isShowing())return;
       System.out.println("Yeah !!!!");
    }
});

Comment: Here is the link to the parent class it is from.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.AccessibleAWTComponent.html